# Replacing dynamic breadcrumb character

Tags: html, css

I just created the below fiddle with the issue

[LIVE ISSUE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc76h/)

**The Code:**

```
<div class="BreadcrumbsBox_0">
    <a href="#" class="BreadcrumbsLink">ABC</a>
    <span class="BreadcrumbsDivider"> &gt; </span>
    <a href="#" class="BreadcrumbsLink">DEF</a>
    <span class="BreadcrumbsDivider"> &gt; </span>
    <span class="Breadcrumbs">g</span>
</div>
```

The HTML that you can see is a structure that is being populated from a dynamic data

what I want is that I need to change ">" i.e the breadcrumb divider to my custom character or a custom background class but when I am trying to put my css, by using :after, visibility:hidden, etc.. it is not showing up what I need are two solutions

1. I can add a custom character by replacing ">" which is coming dynamically
2. I need to create a css class where if I want a background image to be a character, it can be integrated via class.

Awaiting solutions.

*PS: I am looking only for CSS based solutions.*

Comment: _Awaiting solutions_? You should know better.

Comment: I do not know that is why asked, so _awaiting solutions_ - @putvande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mate http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Hc76h/5/

You can use both customise dividers and background image

```
.BreadcrumbsDivider:after {content:"||"}
```

Comment: Thx @Godinall. It works for me. Let me check on all browsers. Anyways, +1 for the efforts.

Comment: You are quite welcome. Mind selecting mine as the answer if not too much trouble. Should have no problem on all browsers/platforms as they are just standard pure css. And if you want you can use data attr to insert dynamical dividers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.BreadcrumbsDivider:before{content:" hello ";color:red;visibility:visible;}
.BreadcrumbsDivider{margin-right:-12px;}
a,.BreadcrumbsDivider{display:inline;}
.BreadcrumbsDivider{visibility:hidden;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc76h/7/)

I have made `.BreadcrumbsDivider` transparent and used pseudo class `:before` to insert text.

Comment: Thx. for your time and efforts, but when you drag to highlight, I can still see the ">" character, as this is a breadcrumb, so it will not look good when users see it. I would have been ideal for on page solution. +1 for your efforts, but still it does not solve my question.

Comment: Yes @Hiral. I can see it working. Let me check on all browsers.